# email from vk django-rest-framework-social-oauth2

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I installed django-rest-framework-social-oauth2 in my project on that tutorial https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2

in my settings file i adding this

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_VK_OAUTH2_SCOPE = [
    'email',
]

SOCIAL_AUTH_VK_EXTRA_DATA = [ 
    ('email', 'email'),
]

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```

when i send request on url /convert-token, created user, but without email field

why email field not receives from VK ?

Comment: Could you clarify what the question is?

Comment: Thank you, i updated my question

Comment: Привет. Попал в ту же самую ситуацию. Вы разобрались как это решается?

Comment: @woe-dev. I switched to this library https://github.com/st4lk/django-rest-social-auth